# El Capitan doesn't allow for modifying built-in apps

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, bash, osx-el-capitan

Does anyone have an idea why trying to modify any of the default, built-in apps' files (Game Center, Notes, Reminders...) with `mv`, `rm` etc. returns "Operation not permitted" on 10.11?

Comment: Post the output of `ls -l` of the file(s) you are trying to `mv` or `rm`, and check if you have the right to do it.

Comment: run `ls -lO /somefolder`. The O option will add a field of either `-` or `Restricted` to the output.

Answer (score 1):

OK, apparently it's because of System Integrity Protection. Disabling it solves the issue. I thought that it wouldn't bother with such non-critical things like app files...